# Ways to detect 2D collision other than OnCollisionEnter2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collider

This might come off as a stupid question, but in an if statement, is it possible to check if the object is currently colliding with another object?

Here is what I had thought of initially (in the code snipit bellow) but for some odd reason that I can't figure out, the variable onFloor is sometimes false when the object is being pushed upwards by the Platform.

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D c)
{
    switch(c.gameObject.tag)
    {
        case "Platform":
            onFloor = true;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D c)
{
    switch(c.gameObject.tag)
    {
        case "Platform":
            onFloor = false;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

And for that reason, I am asking if there are any ways to detect if the circle collider of said object is colliding with box collider of intersecting object while in code.
something like

```
if(CircleCollider2D.CollidingObject != null && CircleCollider2D.CollidingObject.tag == "Platform")
{ /*Code I'd like to do here*/ }
```

Now that's only my imagination trying to think of some way of it that could work but you get the point.

So, I ask, are there any solutions for my imagination?

After discussing with Programmer, IsTouching is underlined and giving the error: 'Collider2D' does not contain a definition for 'IsTouching' and no extension method 'IsTouching' accepting a first argument of type 'Collider2D' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Here is the slimmed down code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    Vector2 jumpVelocity;
    public Collision2D platform;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        jumpVelocity = new Vector2(0, rigidbody2D.gravityScale * 100);
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && collider2D.IsTouching(platform))
        {
            rigidbody2D.AddForce(jumpVelocity, ForceMode2D.Force);
        }
    }
}
```

note that even changing collider2D to a Collision2D variable and taking that variable.collider.IsTouching results the same error.

Comment: My issue is caused by polygon colliders on both sides of the box collider. So I'm guessing that when the circle collider touches one of those, it sends a signal saying it left the box collider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there different solutions than `OnCollisionEnter2D`

**Yes**. Many of them!

`CircleCollider2D`, other 2D colliders and its base class `Collision2D`, have built in functions to do this.

```
public bool IsTouching(Collider2D collider); //Check collision by the provided collider
public bool IsTouchingLayers(); //Check collision by any collision
public bool IsTouchingLayers(int layerMask); //Check collision by layer
public bool OverlapPoint(Vector2 point); //Check collision by position
```

The first function is more appropriate for this.

Simple Example:

```
Collision2D collider1;
Collision2D collider2;

void Update()
{
    //Checks if collider1 is touching with collider2
    if (collider1.collider.IsTouching(collider2.collider))
    {

    }
}
```

Example with the `OnCollisionEnter2D` function:

```
public CircleCollider2D myCircleCollider;

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D c)
{
    if (c.collider.IsTouching(myCircleCollider))
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: My collider2D.IsTouching(otherCollider2D) is giving errors pointing to a missing using directive. The only using directive I have is of UnityEngine. Which using directive am I missing? Would you know?

Comment: It doesn't need any other import except for `UnityEngine` which you already have. Put **Edit** in your question then post the current code that causing the problem.

Comment: `rigidbody2D` and `collider2D` are not declared. You have to declared them at the top then assign them. This code is valid before Unity 4.6. You can no longer use `rigidbody2D` and `collider2D` directly. You have to define them.

Comment: Add `public Rigidbody2D rigidbody2D;` and `public Collider2D collider2D;` to the top. Also, `collider2D.IsTouching(platform)` should be `collider2D.IsTouching(platform.collider)`. I even posted the `IsTouching` function prototype/blueprint in my answer. It takes `Collider2D` as parameter **not** `Collision2D`. Pay attention to the example I provided.

Comment: Problem, when copy pasting your simple example directly, IsTouching still doesn't exist for that example.

Did you mean "This code is *not* valid before Unity 4.6."?

Comment: It was valid until 4.6. Now, it is not valid in 4.6 and above. You have to use `GetComponent` to get the components attached to the GameObject. Soemthing like `gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D >().gravityScale * 100` and `gameObject.GetComponent<Collider2D>().IsTouching(platform.collider)`. Or do it like the way I mentioned in my last comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125123/discussion-between-alox-and-programmer).

Comment: Also shouldn't it be inside `FixedUpdate` and not `Update`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are looking for is the OnCollisionStay method, this one will fire as long as they are touching each other.

There is some more info in the link here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnCollisionStay2D.html